# Implementing css with html file does not work

Tags: python, html, css

I'm a beginner in using html and css files and have been stuck with the following problem for a while.

I made these files but I cannot get the css implemented in the html file:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    greeting = "hello there!"
    return render_template('index.html', greeting=greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>epic website</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" conent="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Sup, {{ greeting }}</h1>
        <p>Praisethelord<p>
        <p class ="x">basinga</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
h1 {
    color:pink;
    font-size: 12px;
}

p {
  color:yellow;
  font-size: 1px;
}

.x {
  color:brown;
}
```

When I open the browser it does use the html file but without the css file (for some reason I cannot show pictures).

When I press f12 to check what's going on, it gives me the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)style.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I have a feeling it has something to do with the directories, but I have been playing around with it for a while and cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Are index.html and style.css in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a static file folder and it should in the same directory.Css files are added to it

```
from flask import Flask, app

app =Flask(__name__,static_url_path='',static_folder='static')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use this structure:

```
project_folder
    | ---------- config.py
    | ---------- app.py
    | ---------- .flaskenv
    | ---------- app/
                  | ---------- routes.py
                  | ---------- __init__.py
                  | ---------- models.py
                  | ---------- templates/
                                   | ---------- index.html
                  | ---------- static/
                                  | ------ css/
                                             | ------ styles.css
```

Your routes go to `rotues.py`, templates will found in *templates* sub-folder, all styles will be in *css* sub-folder.

Initialize your application in `__init__.py` You do not need to use this on this file:

```py
# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Because your top-level file `app.py` will act as the entry point of your application. Eventually, you will have this kind of application:

```py
# __init__.py

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes, models



# routes.py
from app import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def index():
    greeting = "hello there!"
    return render_template('index.html', greeting=greeting)


# app.py
from app import app
```

Templates will be in `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>epic website</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" conent="width=device-width">

        <!-- Dynamic link to styles.css -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/styles.css') }}">

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Sup, {{ greeting }}</h1>
        <p>Praisethelord<p>
        <p class ="x">basinga</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

To run your app, pass flask's environment variables in `.flaskenv`:

```
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=True
```

Run `flask run` in your terminal to start your server.